objectbox database and IntelliJ IDEA
I am trying to set up ObjectBox with IntelliJ IDEA (at macOS ). From the docs I set up the build.gradle code but I can not find the app/build.gradle as the docs write.I tried to set the
apply plugin: "io.objectbox" // Apply last.

at the project build.gradle but it does not work. How can I solve it? I use Kotlin for  JVM
here the docs
https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started
Here is the project build,gradle
buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = "4.0.3" // For Groovy build scripts
    // val objectboxVersion by extra("4.0.3") // For KTS build scripts

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion")
    }
    // Apply plugin after dependencies block so they are not overwritten.
  // apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
}
    plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
       // id("io.objectbox") // Apply last.

    }

    group 'org.example'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
   // ext.objectboxVersion = "3.4.0"


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"


    }

Thank you for your time.

I may download the objectbox as library  but I do not know the right  objectbox library for the JVM

As the docs say, we create a subproject with gradle that idea does not support.

It seems that I solve my issue , I had wrong setup.
I use the examples of docs and this build
buildscript {
    ext.objectboxVersion = "4.0.3" // For Groovy build scripts
    // val objectboxVersion by extra("4.0.3") // For KTS build scripts

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion")
    }
    // Apply plugin after dependencies block so they are not overwritten.
    //apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
    // id("io.objectbox") // Apply last.
    // id("objectbox-publish")

}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
// ext.objectboxVersion = "3.4.0"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()


}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-java:4.0.3")
    // Optional: include all native libraries for distribution
    // (only the one for the current platform is added by the plugin).
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-linux:4.0.3")
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-macos:4.0.3")
    implementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-windows:4.0.3")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"





}
// Apply the plugin after the dependencies block so it detects added
// ObjectBox dependencies and does not replace them.
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

